# Correctly serialize and deserialize DateTime .NET Web Api/Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I want to display the server time in my Blazor app. What I currently do is:

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
        public Task<DtoValue<DateTime>> GetServerLocalTime() 
             => Task.FromResult(new DtoValue<DateTime>(DateTime.Now));
```

with

```cs
public class DtoValue<T>
{
    public DtoValue()
    {
    }

    public DtoValue(T? value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T? Value;
}
```

in my Program.cs I added Newtonsoft:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

The returned value of my WebApi looks like this:

```json
{
  "value": "2023-01-16T23:13:53.0037535+01:00"
}
```

But when I try to deserialize it in my Blazor app:

```cs
var dtoTimeValue = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<DtoValue<DateTime>>("api/Hello/GetServerLocalTime").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My `dtoTimeValue` is the DateTime default value `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

When I manually deserialize the result with NewtonSoft.Json everything is working as expected:

```cs
var result = await HttpClient.GetAsync("api/Hello/GetServerLocalTime").ConfigureAwait(false);
var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var dtoTimeValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DtoValue<DateTime>>(resultString);
```

Why is my Blazor app not able to deserialize the DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only add NewtonSoft to your Server and not your client. It is not required as Json serialiazion is included in .Net now. There are subtle differences in their configuration though.
2. Your DTO is using a field not a property. By default, the serializer is configured not to include fields.

I don't know why your using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` (no need)

I would **recommend** using `DateTimeOffset` not `DateTime`.

```cs
public class DtoValue<T>
{
    public DtoValue()
    {
    }

    public DtoValue(T? value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T? Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class Hello : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<DtoValue<DateTime>> GetServerLocalTime()
        => Task.FromResult(new DtoValue<DateTime>(DateTime.Now));
}
```

```cs
serverDate = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<DtoValue<DateTime>>("api/Hello");
```

Comment: Why does serializing/deserializing a field not work? You are right. As I changed my field to a property, I don't need Newtonsoft on my server anymore and using HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync is working. But I am not sure why.

Comment: @Patrick By default fields are ignored, however you can include them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#serialization-behavior